# Decoding latitude and longitude from 22 byte hex

Tags: binary, hex, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have very long hex values that are meant to encode geo data. I think it's meant to just be latitude and longitude, but the value seems too long for it. I've tried a lot of approaches, and googled it, of course.

Please see the geolocation column:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/139nBExYtYbjhXuLOWFaS5fPT2qHaBmwE/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106348651091773365825&rtpof=true&sd=true

There does seem to be similarity between the values, most end in '240' and start with '0xE6100000010C', with 'C' in the middle. I've not been given clues as to how it is encoded (long story). Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Do not include important information on external links. If the data is important, copy the relevant part (and not too much) directly in the question. If you can, please add the source of such coordinates: this helps a lot. What do you mean with "22 byte hex"? You string has 12 hex digits, and so 6 bytes.

Comment: This dumb interface doesn't have file uploads. Here's some samples, all in Sydney:
0xE6100000010CF9A067B3EAE542C05A10CAFB38286240
0xE6100000010C12DE1E84804C3FC0EB707495EE345D40
0xE6100000010CF5D72B2CB8E740C08D7E349CB2E66240
0xE6100000010C4C2D003219E940C06D82B92719E66240
0xE6100000010C36785F950BC93BC0FD497CEE04286340
0xE6100000010C5BCF108E593E41C05FD38382D2CA6240
0xE6100000010C4E98309A95E341C0490ED8D564806240

Comment: Maybe some variation of https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/help-a-poor-guy-with-this-payload/5014  . I tried with float and double, but no combination make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, might help someone.

This data is SQL geography data type. In SQL you can do:

```
declare @g geography = 0xE6100000010CF9A067B3EAE542C05A10CAFB38286240
select @g.STAsText(), @g.STSrid
```

This will output:

```
POINT (145.256956 -37.796225)   4326
```

You can see what the HEX data is from a long/lat point using:

```
select geography::Point(-37.796225, 145.256956, 4326)
```

Which outputs (same as the original hex string):

```
0xE6100000010CF9A067B3EAE542C05A10CAFB38286240
```

The Microsoft documentation explains all the details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-ver16